# How to modify/remove R rows that don't fit the regex pattern of the column?

Tags: r, regex, stringr, columnsorting

Here is an example of my current column, as well as my desired replacement.

```
Times <- c("12h00","16h30","Afternoon","15h00","14h20","7h30","06h00")
           
Output: ["12","16",NA,"15","14","7","6"]
```

I'm using a messy dataset right now, but I only want the column to contain the hours of each time. The vast majority are in the "##h##" format (07h30).

I assumed `str_replace_all(Time, pattern, replacement)` would work in this scenario, but am having doubts.  I assume this `"^\\d{2}h\\d{2}$"` would be the appropriate code. What is the easiest way to nullify data that does not fit the column pattern?

My  end goal is to create a histogram of 24 bins for each hour of the day, each time is an occurrence of a shark attack.

What do you think?

EDIT: there are a few with the #h## format as in "7h30", while I hope replace that with a plain "7" it isn't 100% necessary due to how few there are.

Comment: What does not fit your regex pattern? What regex pattern did you use?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This is part of the issue, though I assume this "^\\d{2}h\\d{2}$" would be the appropriate code. Everything that doesn't match would be replaced with NA if possible.

Comment: Try `str_extract(Time, '[1-9]\\d*(?=h)')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This works! Thank you so much. As a quick follow up. What would the regex be for "12-Jul-2017", to return only the month between the hyphens? Some say "Reported 12-Jul-2017" as well.

Comment: `"(?<=-)\\w{3}(?=-)"`, `"(?<=-)[A-Za-z]+(?=-)"` or even ``"(?i)(?<=-)(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec){3}(?=-)"``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```r
library(stringr)
Times <- c("12h00","16h30","Afternoon","15h00","14h20","7h30","06h00")
str_extract(Times, '[1-9]\\d*(?=h)')
## => [1] "12" "16" NA   "15" "14" "7"  "6"
```

The pattern will extract

- `[1-9]` - a non-zero digit
- `\d*` - zero or more digits
- `(?=h)` - that are immediately followed with `h`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pqptEE/1) and the [R demo](https://ideone.com/1oRllc).